# Working of try / catch in ZF2

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-db

From the zend documentation i have learned that the try catch can be implemented. when i use zend exception,it cannot be caught even though the try is working

```
try { 
    loadClass() with a non-existant class will cause an exception 
    to be thrown in Zend_Loader: 
    Zend_Loader::loadClass('nonexistantclass'); 
} catch (Zend_Exception $e) { 
    echo "Caught exception"; 
    // Other code to recover from the error 
}
```

**ERROR** :Fatal error: Class 'Album\Controller\Zend\Loader\Loader' not found in C:\wamp\www\zf\module\Album\src\Album\Controller\AlbumController.php on line 22 
The catch is not happening error message is being shown

**EDIT**
But when i throw the exception as in the following code,i get the the message as error.

```
try { throw new \Exception("My exception"); } catch (Exception $e) { echo "Caught exception $e\n"; exit; }
```

Comment: Try to improve the formatting og your question please.

Comment: Please also include the error you're getting. Plus, you've tagged this question with ZF2, but your code is ZF1 code.

Comment: To create an error manager kind of  module wanted to understand the working of try catch.This code was said to be in zend2 by the following documentation @TimFountain.And thank you for helping
[link]
(http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.exception.html)

Comment: @TimFountain:could you please look on my comment and help me

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues here. Despite your code example, the error suggests you *are* using ZF2; and the error is a PHP fatal error, not an exception, which is why your try/catch doesn't work. There is no `Zend_Loader` in ZF2, so PHP won't be able to find that.

I'd suggest just using the standard PHP function `class_exists()` instead:

```
if (class_exists('Some\Class')) {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

which should let you achieve what you're trying to do. No need to worry about exceptions.